# Clean way of inserting data into mongodb through a function in your nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Im new to nodejs and I have this ugly piece of code that I feel should be in its own function but I dont know how to create the function. In my post method I have this long piece of code requesting data from the body and storing it into my mongodb.

```
router.post("/club-affiliation-registration", function (req, res) {
var club = {
    clubName: req.body.clubName,
    clubAddress: req.body.clubAddress,
    clubDisciplines: req.body.clubDisciplines,
    clubEmail: req.body.clubEmail,
    clubWebsite: req.body.clubWebsite,
}

var clubChairperson = {
    firstName: req.body.chairpersonFirstName,
    secondName: req.body.chairpersonLastName,
    phone: req.body.chairpersonPhone,
    email: req.body.chairpersonEmail
}

var clubSecretary = {
    firstName: req.body.secretaryFirstName,
    secondName: req.body.secretaryLastName,
    phone: req.body.secretaryPhone,
    email: req.body.secretaryEmail
}

var clubTreasurer = {
    firstName: req.body.treasurerFirstName,
    secondName: req.body.treasurerLastName,
    phone: req.body.treasurerPhone,
    email: req.body.treasurerEmail
}
var clubChildProtectionOfficer = {
    fullName: req.body.childProtectionOfficerName,
    phone: req.body.childProtectionOfficerMobile,
    email: req.body.childProtectionOfficerEmail
}
var meta = {
    clubPaymentId: result.transaction.id
}
// storing in database
var newClub = {
                club: club,
                clubChairperson: clubChairperson,
                clubSecretary: clubSecretary,
                clubTreasurer: clubTreasurer,
                clubChildProtectionOfficer: clubChildProtectionOfficer,
                meta: meta
            }
Club.create(newClub, function (error, newlyCreatedClub) {
                if (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                } else {
                    req.flash("success", "You Application has been submitted. Please save your payment number: " + result.transaction.id);
                    res.redirect("/about");
                }
            });
});
```

Is it possible to put this data im requesting into its own function and just call it from the post method? How would that be achieved?

My club schema

```
var ClubSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
// first page
club: {
    clubName: String,
    clubAddress: String,
    clubDisciplines: String,
    clubEmail: String,
    clubWebsite: String,
    clubSponsor: String
},
// second page
clubChairperson: {
    firstName: String,
    secondName: String,
    phone: String,
    email: String
},
clubSecretary: {
    firstName: String,
    secondName: String,
    phone: String,
    email: String
},
clubTreasurer: {
    firstName: String,
    secondName: String,
    phone: String,
    email: String
},
clubChildProtectionOfficer: {
    fullName: String,
    phone: String,
    email: String
},
meta:{
    clubSubmission : { type : Date, default: Date.now },
    clubPaymentId: String
}

});
```

Comment: Can you show us your `Club` model schema definition? You could do with a model redesign, perhaps create a separate users collection that holds pertinent info such as `firstName`, `secondName`, `phone` and `email` as the current schema violates the DRY principle (`D`on't `R`epeat `Y`ourself).

Comment: @chridam I just added it. I tried putting all of the req.body's into a function and returning newClub but I get an error `Cannot read property 'body' of undefined`

Comment: @chridam Thanks for that. I applied it to my schema now but it wasn't related to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on MVC architecture, Controllers are resposible for communications between data and your client requests. so you could define all your callback functions to your http verbs include get, post, delete, ... in a controller.

**routes/router.js**

```
var controller = require('../controllers/controller.js');

router
    .route("/club-affiliation-registration")
        .get(controller.getRegistration)
        .post(controller.postRegistration);
```

**controllers/controller.js**

```
var Club = require('../models/club.js');

module.exports = {

    getRegistration: function(req, res) {},

    postRegistration: function(req, res) {
        var club = {
            clubName: req.body.clubName,
            clubAddress: req.body.clubAddress,
            clubDisciplines: req.body.clubDisciplines,
            clubEmail: req.body.clubEmail,
            clubWebsite: req.body.clubWebsite,
        };

        var clubChairperson = {
            firstName: req.body.chairpersonFirstName,
            secondName: req.body.chairpersonLastName,
            phone: req.body.chairpersonPhone,
            email: req.body.chairpersonEmail
        };

        var clubSecretary = {
            firstName: req.body.secretaryFirstName,
            secondName: req.body.secretaryLastName,
            phone: req.body.secretaryPhone,
            email: req.body.secretaryEmail
        };

        var clubTreasurer = {
            firstName: req.body.treasurerFirstName,
            secondName: req.body.treasurerLastName,
            phone: req.body.treasurerPhone,
            email: req.body.treasurerEmail
        };

        var clubChildProtectionOfficer = {
            fullName: req.body.childProtectionOfficerName,
            phone: req.body.childProtectionOfficerMobile,
            email: req.body.childProtectionOfficerEmail
        };

        var meta = {
            clubPaymentId: result.transaction.id
        };

        // storing in database
        var newClub = {
            club: club,
            clubChairperson: clubChairperson,
            clubSecretary: clubSecretary,
            clubTreasurer: clubTreasurer,
            clubChildProtectionOfficer: clubChildProtectionOfficer,
            meta: meta
        };

        Club.create(newClub, function(error, newlyCreatedClub) {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error);
            } else {
                req.flash("success", "You Application has been submitted. Please save your payment number: " + result.transaction.id);
                res.redirect("/about");
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: This is something that I was looking for. That made things a lot cleaner. I will have to look more into controllers so I can understand it better.